# window.screen.width do not work on ios devices?

Tags: javascript, html, ios

I have sphere animation on my site, for desktop, tablet and mobile I m using different sizes of sphere. Here you can see conditions of every type of device:

```
desktop:
var screen_size = window.screen.width;
if(screen_size < 1025){
    false;
}else{
    sphere animation code;
}
Tablet:
var screen_size = window.screen.width;
if(screen_size >= 1025  || screen_size  < 668){
    false;
}else{
    sphere animation code;
}
Mobile:
var screen_size = window.screen.width;
if((screen_size > 667)){
    false;
}else{
    sphere animation code;
}
```

If I use one script separately its  - works, other operation system - its works. I think suppose main problem in **"window.screen.width".**

Here you an see my site with full code: t[hesevenwang](https://thesevenwang.com/)

Comment: It's not related to the OS but the version of the Browser you are using

Comment: Why are you redefining ```screen_size``` over and over?

Comment: Plus ```screen.width``` returns the width of the device being emulated, rather than the host computer's screen. And that's a problem for safari. Use ```window.innerWidth``` instead it should work

Comment: Just change all  "window.screen.width"  to  window.innerWidth - still not work. I suppose IOS because this problem happen only on IOS devices.

Comment: https://ryanve.com/lab/dimensions/#device Shows that it works in iOS, but the size is likely smaller than you think. An iPhone 13 Pro has a width of 390

Comment: oh yeah you are gonna need to add more media queries values for your code to work on multiple ranges of devices plus I recommend you verify for width by evaluating the size by between like ```(350 > screen_size &&  screen_size< 400)``` so that you target a bigger device audience

Answer (score 0):

Thank all for replies, problem was not in  ("window.screen.width" not work on IOS) or conditions.

Problem was in 3 spheres with same code, after I deleted all repeated code it start work. May be some double variables cause an error implementation.

And window.screen.width now work well on IOS, so my main problem statement was wrong.

Anyway thank you all, you comments helped me think under the problem more clearly.